# Can anyone help with this hasNextLine() error?

Tags: java, graph, dft

Having problems compiling this class. I'm working through a book on java and this is one of the exercises, and they provide most of the code. So this is basically a stock class provided by the book.

Now, the problem I'm having is when compiling i'm getting this error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method hasNextLine()
location: class StdIn
```

In relation to this:

```
// read a graph from an input stream
    public Graph(In in, String delimiter) {
        st = new ST<String, SET<String>>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            String[] names = line.split(delimiter);
            for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                addEdge(names[0], names[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I thought hasNextLine() was part of the Scanner library, which is imported in the class StdIn, so it shouldn't be missing..?

> import java.util.Scanner;

Here is the full code for class Graph (where the error occurs), if it helps!

Many thanks!

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac Graph.java
 *  Dependencies: ST.java SET.java In.java
 *  
 *  Undirected graph data type implemented using a symbol table
 *  whose keys are vertices (String) and whose values are sets
 *  of neighbors (SET of Strings).
 *
 *  Remarks
 *  -------
 *   - Parallel edges are not allowed
 *   - Self-loop are allowed
 *   - Adjacency lists store many different copies of the same
 *     String. You can use less memory by interning the strings.
 *
 *************************************************************************/

public class Graph {

    // symbol table: key = string vertex, value = set of neighboring vertices
    private ST<String, SET<String>> st;

    // number of edges
    private int E;

    // create an empty graph
    public Graph() {
        st = new ST<String, SET<String>>();
    }

    // read a graph from an input stream
    public Graph(In in, String delimiter) {
        st = new ST<String, SET<String>>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            String[] names = line.split(delimiter);
            for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                addEdge(names[0], names[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    // return number of vertices and edges
    public int V() { return st.size(); }
    public int E() { return E;         }

    // return the degree of vertex v 
    public int degree(String v) {
        if (!st.contains(v)) return 0;
        else return st.get(v).size();
    }

    // add w to v's set of neighbors, and add v to w's set of neighbors
    public void addEdge(String v, String w) {
        if (!hasEdge(v, w)) E++;
        if (!hasVertex(v)) addVertex(v);
        if (!hasVertex(w)) addVertex(w);
        st.get(v).add(w);
        st.get(w).add(v);
    }

    // add a new vertex v with no neighbors (if vertex does not yet exist)
    public void addVertex(String v) {
        if (!hasVertex(v)) st.put(v, new SET<String>());
    }

    // return iterator over all vertices in graph
    public Iterable<String> vertices() {
        return st;
    }

    // return an iterator over the neighbors of vertex v
    public Iterable<String> adjacentTo(String v) {
        // return empty set if vertex isn't in graph
        if (!hasVertex(v)) return new SET<String>();
        else               return st.get(v);
    }

    // is v a vertex in the graph?
    public boolean hasVertex(String v) {
        return st.contains(v);
    }

    // is v-w an edge in the graph?
    public boolean hasEdge(String v, String w) {
        if (!hasVertex(v)) return false;
        return st.get(v).contains(w);
    }

    // not very efficient, intended for debugging only
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (String v : st) {
            s += v + ": ";
            for (String w : st.get(v)) {
                s += w + " ";
            }
            s += "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph G = new Graph();
        G.addEdge("A", "B");
        G.addEdge("A", "C");
        G.addEdge("C", "D");
        G.addEdge("D", "E");
        G.addEdge("D", "G");
        G.addEdge("E", "G");
        G.addVertex("H");

        // print out graph
        StdOut.println(G);

        // print out graph again by iterating over vertices and edges
        for (String v : G.vertices()) {
            StdOut.print(v + ": ");
            for (String w : G.adjacentTo(v)) {
                StdOut.print(w + " ");
            }
            StdOut.println();
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the class StdIn, again if it helps!

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac StdIn.java
 *  Execution:    java StdIn
 *
 *  Reads in data of various types from standard input.
 *
 *************************************************************************/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

/**
 *  <i>Standard input</i>. This class provides methods for reading strings
 *  and numbers from standard input.
 *  <p>
 *  The Locale used is: language = English, country = US. This is consistent
 *  with the formatting conventions with Java floating-point literals,
 *  command-line arguments (via <tt>Double.parseDouble()</tt>)
 *  and standard output (via <tt>System.out.print()</tt>). It ensures that
 *  standard input works the number formatting used in the textbook.
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation, see <a href="http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/15inout">Section 1.5</a> of
 *  <i>Introduction to Programming in Java: An Interdisciplinary Approach</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 */
public final class StdIn {

    // assume Unicode UTF-8 encoding
    private static String charsetName = "UTF-8";

    // assume language = English, country = US for consistency with System.out.
    private static Locale usLocale = new Locale("en", "US");

    // the scanner object
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), charsetName);

    // static initializer
    static { scanner.useLocale(usLocale); }

    // singleton pattern - can't instantiate
    private StdIn() { }


    /**
     * Is there only whitespace left on standard input?
     */
    public static boolean isEmpty() {
         return !scanner.hasNext();
    }

    /**
     * Return next string from standard input
     */
    public static String readString() {
        return scanner.next();
    }

    /**
     * Return next int from standard input
     */
    public static int readInt() {
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

    /**
     * Return next double from standard input
     */
    public static double readDouble() {
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    /**
     * Return next float from standard input
     */
    public static float readFloat() {
         return scanner.nextFloat();
    }

    /**
     * Return next short from standard input
     */
    public static short readShort() {
         return scanner.nextShort();
    }

    /**
     * Return next long from standard input
     */
    public static long readLong() {
        return scanner.nextLong();
    }

    /**
     * Return next byte from standard input
     */
    public static byte readByte() {
        return scanner.nextByte();
    }

    /**
     * Return next boolean from standard input, allowing "true" or "1" for true,
     * and "false" or "0" for false
     */
    public static boolean readBoolean() {
        String s = readString();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))  return true;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) return false;
        if (s.equals("1"))               return true;
        if (s.equals("0"))               return false;
        throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
    }

    /**
     * Return rest of line from standard input
     */
    public static String readLine() {
        return scanner.nextLine();
    }

    /**
     * Return next char from standard input
     */
    // a complete hack and inefficient - email me if you have a better
    public static char readChar() {
        // (?s) for DOTALL mode so . matches a line termination character
        // 1 says look only one character ahead
        // consider precompiling the pattern
        String s = scanner.findWithinHorizon("(?s).", 1);
        return s.charAt(0);
    }

    /**
     * Return rest of input from standard input
     */
    public static String readAll() {
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) return null;

        // reference: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner_1.html
        return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }




    /**
     * Unit test
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Type a string: ");
        String s = StdIn.readString();
        System.out.println("Your string was: " + s);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Type an int: ");
        int a = StdIn.readInt();
        System.out.println("Your int was: " + a);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Type a boolean: ");
        boolean b = StdIn.readBoolean();
        System.out.println("Your boolean was: " + b);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Type a double: ");
        double c = StdIn.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Your double was: " + c);
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

And if needed, here is class In: (this is a bit lengthy sorry)

```
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac In.java
 *  Execution:    java In
 *
 *  Reads in data of various types from: stdin, file, URL.
 *
 *  % java In
 *
 *  Remarks
 *  -------
 *    - isEmpty() returns true if there is no more input or
 *      it is all whitespace. This might lead to surprising behavior
 *      when used with readChar()
 *
 *************************************************************************/


import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


/**
 *  <i>Input</i>. This class provides methods for reading strings
 *  and numbers from standard input, file input, URL, and socket.
 *  <p>
 *  The Locale used is: language = English, country = US. This is consistent
 *  with the formatting conventions with Java floating-point literals,
 *  command-line arguments (via <tt>Double.parseDouble()</tt>)
 *  and standard output (via <tt>System.out.print()</tt>). It ensures that
 *  standard input works the number formatting used in the textbook.
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation, see <a href="http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/31datatype">Section 3.1</a> of
 *  <i>Introduction to Programming in Java: An Interdisciplinary Approach</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 */
public final class In {
    private Scanner scanner;

    // assume Unicode UTF-8 encoding
    //private String charsetName = "UTF-8";

    private String charsetName = "ISO-8859-1";

    // assume language = English, country = US for consistency with System.out.
    private Locale usLocale = new Locale("en", "US");

   /**
     * Create an input stream for standard input.
     */
    public In() {
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), charsetName);
        scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
    }

   /**
     * Create an input stream from a socket.
     */
    public In(Socket socket) {
        try {
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(is), charsetName);
            scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not open " + socket);
        }
    }

   /**
     * Create an input stream from a URL.
     */
    public In(URL url) {
        try {
            URLConnection site = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is     = site.getInputStream();
            scanner            = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(is), charsetName);
            scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not open " + url);
        }
    }

   /**
     * Create an input stream from a file or web page.
     */
    public In(String s) {

        try {
            // first try to read file from local file system
            File file = new File(s);
            if (file.exists()) {
                scanner = new Scanner(file, charsetName);
                scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
                return;
            }

            // next try for files included in jar
            URL url = getClass().getResource(s);

            // or URL from web
            if (url == null) { url = new URL(s); }

            URLConnection site = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is     = site.getInputStream();
            scanner            = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(is), charsetName);
            scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not open " + s);
        }
    }

   /**
     * Does the input stream exist?
     */
    public boolean exists()  {
        return scanner != null;
    }

   /**
     * Is the input stream empty?
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return !scanner.hasNext();
    }

   /**
     * Read and return the next line.
     */
    public String readLine() {
        String line = null;
        try                 { line = scanner.nextLine(); }
        catch (Exception e) {                            }
        return line;
    }

   /**
     * Read and return the next character.
     */
    public char readChar() {
        // (?s) for DOTALL mode so . matches any character, including a line termination character
        // 1 says look only one character ahead
        // consider precompiling the pattern
        String s = scanner.findWithinHorizon("(?s).", 1);
        return s.charAt(0);
    }



    // return rest of input as string
   /**
     * Read and return the remainder of the input as a string.
     */
    public String readAll() {
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) { return null; }

        // reference: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner_1.html
        return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }



   /**
     * Return the next string from the input stream.
     */
    public String  readString() {
        return scanner.next();
    }

   /**
     * Return the next int from the input stream.
     */
    public int readInt() {
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

   /**
     * Return the next double from the input stream.
     */
    public double readDouble() {
        return scanner.nextDouble();
    }

   /**
     * Return the next float from the input stream.
     */
    public double readFloat() {
        return scanner.nextFloat();
    }

   /**
     * Return the next long from the input stream.
     */
    public long readLong() {
        return scanner.nextLong();
    }

   /**
     * Return the next byte from the input stream.
     */
    public byte readByte() {
        return scanner.nextByte();
    }


   /**
     * Return the next boolean from the input stream, allowing "true" or "1"
     * for true and "false" or "0" for false.
     */
    public boolean readBoolean() {
        String s = readString();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))  return true;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) return false;
        if (s.equals("1"))               return true;
        if (s.equals("0"))               return false;
        throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
    }


   /**
     * Close the input stream.
     */
    public void close() { scanner.close();  }



   /**
     * Test client.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in;
        String urlName = "http://www.cs.princeton.edu/IntroCS/stdlib/InTest.txt";

        // read from a URL
        System.out.println("readAll() from URL " + urlName);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In(urlName);
            System.out.println(in.readAll());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();

        // read one line at a time from URL
        System.out.println("readLine() from URL " + urlName);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In(urlName);
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();

        // read one string at a time from URL
        System.out.println("readString() from URL " + urlName);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In(urlName);
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readString();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();


        // read one line at a time from file in current directory
        System.out.println("readLine() from current directory");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In("./InTest.txt");
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();


        // read one line at a time from file using relative path
        System.out.println("readLine() from relative path");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In("../stdlib/InTest.txt");
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();

        // read one char at a time
        System.out.println("readChar() from file");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In("InTest.txt");
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                char c = in.readChar();
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // read one line at a time from absolute OS X / Linux path
        System.out.println("readLine() from absolute OS X / Linux path");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        in = new In("/n/fs/csweb/introcs/stdlib/InTest.txt");
        try {
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();


        // read one line at a time from absolute Windows path
        System.out.println("readLine() from absolute Windows path");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        try {
            in = new In("G:\\www\\introcs\\stdlib\\InTest.txt");
            while (!in.isEmpty()) {
                String s = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Importing* a class isn't the same as *inheriting* from it. It just means that the source file knows about that type.

If you're going to call `foo.hasNextLine()` and expect the `Scanner.hasNextLine()` method to be called, then the type of `foo` must either be `Scanner` or some subclass.

Your `StdIn` class doesn't *extend* `Scanner` - it *contains* a `Scanner`. So one option would be to add an extra method to delegate the `hasNextLine` method:

```
public static bool hasNextLine() {
    return scanner.hasNextLine();
}
```

Note that this is a *static* method though, and shouldn't be called via a reference as you're doing in your original code:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
```

that should be

```
while (StdIn.hasNextLine()) {
```

to make it clear that it's a static method - that it doesn't depend on the state of the object that `in` refers to. Accessing a static member as if it were an instance member is legal Java, but bad practice.

(The same is true of your other calls through `in`, of course. Given that it's just calling static methods, you don't need the parameter at all.)

Comment: Ok thanks very much! That compiles fine now using that static boolean method! I'll test and see how it goes! Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are missing a lot of import statements. You need to import all classes you are using except the ones in java.lang.

Comment: I tried importing java.util.*; and java.io.*; and neither solved it

Comment: No, this isn't a matter of missing import statements. It's trying to call a method on a class which doesn't *have* that method.